# Binding List<T> to DataGridView in WinForm

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, binding, grid

I have a class

```
class Person{
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public string Surname {get; set;}
}
```

and a `List<Person>` to which I add some items. The list is bound to my `DataGridView`.

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person(){Name="Joe", Surname="Black"});
persons.Add(new Person(){Name="Misha", Surname="Kozlov"});
myGrid.DataSource = persons;
```

There is no problem. `myGrid` displays two rows, but when I add new items to my `persons` list, `myGrid` does not show new updated list. It only shows the two rows which I added before.

So what is the problem?

Rebinding every time works well. But when I bind a `DataTable` to the grid when every time when I make some changes to `DataTable` there is not any need to ReBind `myGrid`.

How to solve it without rebinding every time?

Comment: The accessor of {get; set;} must be added for datagridview to show.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

List does not implement `IBindingList` so the grid does not know about your new items.

Bind your DataGridView to a `BindingList<T>` instead.

```
var list = new BindingList<Person>(persons);
myGrid.DataSource = list;
```

But I would even go further and bind your grid to a `BindingSource`

```
var list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person { Name = "Joe", },
    new Person { Name = "Misha", },
};
var bindingList = new BindingList<Person>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
grid.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: It says that you can use IList and other interfaces aswell : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx

Comment: @Pacane: Sure you can, but the DataGridView needs to know if your datasource has any changes. `One` way ist to use a BindingList, which will Raise an event if the underlying list changes. Another way is to use a `BindingSource` and call ResetBinding() everytime you add/delete a Row but thats way more work. If you want to inform the Grid about property changes the easiest way is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: why did u use BindingList and BindingSource because we can directly bind list to datagridview datasource property. discuss the importance of BindingList and BindingSource u used here. thanks

Comment: @Mou You can bind a DataGrid to a `List<T>` if you want. But if you programatically add items to the List DataGridView will not know about it because you List doesn't implent `IBindingList`. Regarding BindingSource: I use winforms a lot, and I don't bind to anything else than a BindingSource - FULLSTOP. To add more details is too much for a comment, but `BindingSource` has so much to offer without any disadvantages. I would go so far and say `Anyone who does not use a BindingSource for binding has not fully understood windows forms databindings`

Comment: @Jürgen: "has not fully understood windows forms databindings". Well, that's most people, to be fair. Myself included. Why the extra fluff. I get how to do it it's just why it's done this way i don't get.

Comment: @CraigBrett Consider `BindingSource` as a bridge between your datasource and your GUI. It solves many databinding related problems. You want to reload your data? Just set `bindingSource.DataSource` to your new collection instead of rebinding every control. Your DataSource can be null? Set `bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(YourClass)` You want to have an editable grid but your datasource does not have a parameterless constructor? Just implement `bindingSource.AddingNew` event and create the object yourself. I never experienced a downside while using `BindingSource` but lots of benefits.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this discussion. When the list changes should the changes show up in the datagridview automatically?

Comment: Was anyone successful in making this auto update? I can't get it to work, neither did https://stackoverflow.com/q/23507139/640195

Comment: Nope, I modified the List behind the BindingSource and the GUI doesn't refresh. Maybe there are some restrictions? Does the `Person` need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @joe that depends. If you change one persons properties and expect to see the result in the GUI: yes. if you add / remove items from the list, this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @joe Update: Please keep in mind, that you have to modify the BindingList instead of the List<Person> or create a `class PersonList, List<Person> : IBindingList` and implement `IBindingList` yourself

Answer (score 5):

Every time you add a new element to the List you need to re-bind your Grid.
Something like:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Joe", Surname = "Black" });
persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Misha", Surname = "Kozlov" });
dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;

// added a new item
persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Surname = "Doe" });
// bind to the updated source
dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
```

Comment: I cannot see dataSource property under datagrid.Can you tell me how do I use it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to do with out rebinding by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

Pretty Simple example is available here,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: That is not sufficient, if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` the DataGridView will show all property changes that happen in the background, but it will not know if you add / delete a row from your source. For this purpose there is an `IBindingList` interface and, for your convinience, an implmentation `BindingList<T>` that already implements it, but does not support sorting/filtering.

Comment: Yes, I would agree with you. so I think ObservableCollection<T> can be used for this. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

After adding new item to `persons` add:

```
myGrid.DataSource = null;
myGrid.DataSource = persons;
```

Comment: I cannot see dataSource property under datagrid.Can you tell me how do I use it?

Comment: This suggestion could cause issues. For example, you could find that a click on an item in the grid could get an _IndexOutOfRangeException_ as the datasource is null at that point.  It would be wiser to bind to a _BindingList_ initially and implement _INotifyPropertyChanged_ on your object as other answers indicate

Comment: What is the point of assigning it to `null` if you immediately assign it to `persons` on the next line?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the issue I had, but if anyone is looking to convert a BindingList of any type to List of the same type, then this is how it is done:

```
var list = bindingList.ToDynamicList();
```

Also, if you're assigning BindingLists of dynamic types to a DataGridView.DataSource, then make sure you declare it first as IBindingList so the above works.