# Find USBportname with c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, netduino

For a project i have to communicate with a netduino,
So i use serial communication to communicate with the netduino.

But here's my problem
I cannot find my Usb portname, i use this small piece of code to find the port names.

```
 private void GetPortNames()
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            ComportListbox.DataSource = ports;
        }
```

It doesnt show the usb port names.
What am i doeing wrong, or how can i fix this issue.

**EDIT**

Question edited:

Can i see the usbportname from my usbport where the NETduino is attached to. So i hope to see COM10 for example. I looked in the system managment and saw that the usb is called `Port_#0001.Hub_#0001`. How can i open this port.

Comment: What serial communication has to do with usb portname? What do you expect to see in the list of com-ports?

Comment: Sinatr, Like i said i'm communicating with a netduino witch is connected to a usb port. I want to know the port name of the usb port. SerialPort.GetPortNames(); looked like the right way to go.

Comment: I might misunderstood you. Does listbox shows `com1`, `com2`, etc. or is it **blank**? Do you want to see `com5` and it is not there or what do you want to see?

Comment: The listbox is blank, i checked the array but that is empty also

Comment: Still it is unclear what do you *expect* to see. [`GetPortNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx) will return  a list of *serial* ports, while you saying *usb*. If it's a usb-to-serial converter of some sort, then you get something like `com5` from it and this function should return it. If you don't see it, then perhaps your hardware is not working/powered/connected, etc.

Comment: If your array is empty, nothing else will work :(

Comment: I have edited the question so it will be easier to understand(i hope)

Comment: You should add the .Items.Add code to your example so people won't think that it is the DataSource part that is not working.

Comment: Serial ports are very primitive devices, they don't support plug & play.  So there is no way to find out what's connected to a specific COM port.  You can usually dig out more info about the ports with System.Management and the Win32_SerialPort class.  You'll get a vendor name.  Download [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to play with queries, it also auto-generates the code you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ComportListbox has an "add" method, why not just use that with a for loop.

```
foreach ( string portName in ports )
{
   ComportListbox.Items.Add( portName );
}
```

If not, let me know and I will delete this answer.

Otherwise you may have to use a `BindingList<string>`.  see: [Binding List<T> to DataGridView in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform)

Or you might even have to create an object that contains a string property for the binding name.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Comportlistbox doesnt have a Add function. But maybe i can make a array and at the portnames in there and later insert define the array as a Datasource for the ListBox

Comment: You might be able to do ComportListbox.Items.Add( portName );  It is hard to know, couldn't find api for Comportlistbox.

Comment: I don't know if BindingList<string> would work, or if you would have to make a new class "MyPort" with a property "PortName" and make a BindingList<PortName>.

Comment: The ComportListbox.items.add does work but the problem is that the ports string is empty