# Increamental loading in grid using DataTable as DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, lazy-loading

In my window application there are many screens with grid. 
And I have used DataTable as DataSource of the grid and DataTable have some really large data sets (> 50,000), which take a lot time to load data on screen if we load all at a time while loading the UI get un-responsive till all data not get loaded,
 So that I have implemented incremental loading in that grid using `Background Worker`.
Here is the code :

```
// DoWork Event of the background Wroker.
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            while (bgstop)
            {                   
                e.Result = addNewRecord(); 
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Result) == false)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;                       
                    bgstop = false;
                    killBGWorker();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    // to add/merge the records in the DataTable
    private bool addNewRecord()
    {
        int flag = 0;
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500); //optional
            DataTable tableAdd = getTableData();
            if (tableAdd.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dtRecords.Merge(tableAdd);  // dtRecords is the DataTable which attached to grid
                flag++;
            }
            else
                backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (flag > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    // To get the next slot of Records from the DataBase
    private DataTable getTableData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        start = nextRows * noOfRows;
        stop = start + noOfRows;
        dt = SQLHelper.getAllRecords(totalRows,noOfRows, start + 1, stop);
        nextRows++;
        return dt;
    }

    // kill the backgroudworker after the all data/records get loaded from  database to grid/DataTable 
    private void killBGWorker()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Above code get the first defined number of records (say 200) and after that in the background worker started and start fetching the data in a slot and merge that with grid DataSource till all data (say >50,000 records) get loaded into the grid.
But still have some issue with UI interaction, UI not get hang for 2-3 seconds many time till all records from DataBase get loaded into the grid.
I gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform) but in that example DataModel was used but in my case there is no DataModel they just fetched in DataTable from DataBase and right now we can't move to DataModel.
 Is there any other way to achieve incremental Loading with good UI interaction ?
OR
 Is there any way to implement `IBindingList` in current scenario ?

Comment: Is it acceptable to simply have the UI remain responsive, or is it important for you to retrieve rows incrementally? Is the user allowed to interact with a partial dataset?

Comment: For good user experience I need to retrieve rows incrementally. And yes user are allowed to interact with a partial dataset.

Comment: Did user view all your grids at the same time ?

Comment: @NamBình : Possible! I am using MDI form in which there are multiple screen/forms are present, user can open multiple form.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by changing the DataGridView from BindingMode to [`VirtualMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.90).aspx).

The following changes will re-use as much as possible what you already have and you will see that the DataGridView gets loaded incrementally. I don't know how much records you fetch at once, but you can keep that number low.

Set the property `VirtualMode` to true. Remove any values from the property `DataSource`. Add as many Unbounded columns to your DataGridView as you have columns in your DataGrid (this could be done automatic if needed).

Add an eventhandler for [`CellValueNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalueneeded(v=vs.90).aspx).

Add the following code to that handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = dtRecords.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex];
}
```

On you backgroundworker1 set the property [`WorkerReportsProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress(v=vs.110).aspx) to True
Add an eventhandler to your backgroundworker for [`ProgressChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx).with the following code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.RowCount = (int) e.UserState;
}
```

In your method `addNewRecord` add below this line:

```
dtRecords.Merge(tableAdd);  // dtRecords is the DataTable which attached to grid
// added to bring the number of records to the UI thread
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(42, dtRecords.Rows.Count);
```

And with that your datagridview should now load its data incrementally. The trick really is setting the `RowCount` property. That signals to the datagrid if it can show a record and it adapts its scrollbar to the same.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation. But what if I am not using DataGridView? Instead of DGV I am using third party(syncfusion,telrik etc) grid. I want such solution which does not depends on UI control.

Comment: I see. With VirtualMode it becomes a pull model, The DGV decides when to ask for items. If you use a BindingSource it becomes a push model, and when the collection changes the control needs to go over the complete list again to find out what it needs to do. That takes not only time but is probably also done on the UI thread which explains the lagging you see. You could try if setting [RaiseListChangeEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.raiselistchangedevents(v=vs.110).aspx) to false on the bindingsource when you call `Merge` helps.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is using `BindingSource` like this:

```
    // To take data in silent
    BackgroundWorker m_oWorker;

    // To hold my data. tblDuToanPhanBo is my data type
    List<tblDuToanPhanBo> lst2 = new List<tblDuToanPhanBo>();

    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    // replace 50000 with your total data count
    int totalData = 500000;

    // No of rows to load a time by BackgroundWorker
    int RowsToTake = 2000;

    // No of rows loaded
    int RowsTaken = 0;
```

Take first portion of data and let `BackgroundWorker` do the rest:

```
    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        m_oWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);
        m_oWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler (m_oWorker_ProgressChanged);
        m_oWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler (m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        // QLQT is my DataContext
        using (QLQT db = new QLQT())
        {
            lst2.AddRange(db.tblDuToanPhanBos.Skip(RowsTaken).Take(RowsToTake).ToList());
        }
        RowsTaken = lst2.Count;
        bs.DataSource = lst2;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

`BackgroundWorker` to take one portion of data:

```
    void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Load data
        using (QLQT db = new QLQT())
        {
            lst2.AddRange(db.tblDuToanPhanBos.Skip(RowsTaken).Take(RowsToTake).ToList());
        }
        // Update number of rows loaded
        RowsTaken = lst2.Count;
        if (((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

When `BackgroundWorker` is completed, update `BindingSource`, run `BackgroundWorker` against until all data loaded:

```
    void m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loading Cancelled.");
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error while performing background operation.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (lst2.Count < totalData)
            {
                bs.ResetBindings(false);
                m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                bs.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks for nice code, but I already mentioned that i haven't DataModel for my application and I am using DataTable as DataSource. And second thing is I had also thinking of calling `DoWork` again from `RunWorkerCompleted` but after going through [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254728/backgroundworker-starting-again-in-completed-event) link, I changed my mind.

Comment: Is it ok for create new `BackgroundWorker` after one's `DoWork` completed instead of re-use ? `BindingSource`'s `DataSource` can be set as `DataTable` instead of `List`, the reason I use `BindingSource` here is it does not need me to reset `DataGrid`/`DataGridView`'s `DataSource` each time. I'm not good as using `DataTable` so I do not use it much (except for reporting). Hope you find another solution soon :)
Ps: I did not tested with `DataTable` but I think it work. Maybe when I have time. The result with `List` with about 100,000 records is acceptable