# Can't load data in DataGridView from List

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to show the data from my database in a `DataGridView` in my windows forms application, but for some reason when I use the `DataSource` property that wont work, here is my code (its just a dummy list I'm using so I can see what I'm doing wrong).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Client> list = new List<Client>();
    Client client1 = new Client(1, "joro", "2014-12-12", 5);
    Client client2 = new Client(2, "moro", "2015-1-12", 3);
    list.Add(client1);
    list.Add(client2);
    dataGridClients.DataSource = list;
}
```

and the "client" class (its the same as the table in my data base from where I want to put the info in the grid)

```
public class Client
{
    private int clientId;
    private string clientName;
    private string dateStarted;
    private int cycleLength;

    public Client(int id, string name, string date, int length)
    {
        clientId = id;
        clientName = name;
        dateStarted = date;
        cycleLength = length;
    }
}
```

So when the form loads there is nothing in the data grid. I'm pretty new in this and I never used data grid before so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `Client`? include code for it as well, please

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you set `DataGridView.DataSource` value, grid should create columns for `public` `properties` of objects in List

you have only `private` `variables` in `Client` class. Create corresponding properties

```
public class Client
{
   private int clientId;
   // editable property => editable column
   public int ClientId { get { return clientId; } set {clientId = value;} }

   private string clientName;
   // readonly property => readonly column
   public string ClientName { get { return clientName; } }

   // ... same for the rest variables
}
```

Comment: @НиколаХилендаров, this particular moment with dataGridView often causes some confusion. if my answer helped, mark it as accepted, please. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Bind Data after give DataSource.

```
dataGridClients.DataBind();
```

and set `autogeneratecolumns="true"` for all data else you must manually bind your grid for appropriate field.

```
<asp:gridview id="dataGridClients" 
  autogeneratecolumns="True"
  emptydatatext="No data available."  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To add new data into list you can do it directory example as below

```
List<Client> list = new List<Client>();
            list.Add(new Client { x = 1, s = "", d = "", dd = 2 });
```

Step 1 Create class entity

```
public class Client
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public string s { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
    public int dd { get; set; }
}
```

2nd add data into class entities

```
 List<Client> list = new List<Client>();
            list.Add(new Client { x = 1, s = "", d = "", dd = 2 });
            list.Add(new Client { x = 1, s = "", d = "", dd = 2 });
```

finally add data source to DG

```
dataGridClients.DataSource = list;
```