# Bind different lists into columns in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have dynamic list item. This list is not static. In view of the necessity, I will have at least one/more list. what I need is, I gotta split that list into at least two unique records. This I can part. Yet, I need to bind this list into datagridview.

This is my code: I have two list,

```
  List<string> list1=new List<string>();
  list1.add("THE BOOK OF BURGER");
  list1.add("The Hogwarts Library");
  list1.add("NEW Day in the Life of a Farmer");

  List<string> list2=new List<string>();
  list2.add("$200");
  list2.add("$150");
  list2.add("$170");

  .....
  list3,
  list4.. etc..
```

I have Datagridview. I want to bind this into data grid view as,
 [image]

how might I add datasource to this datagridview? I tired to include this into datatable. In any case, I couldn't accomplish this. Any help would be truly valued.

Comment: You can create a `BooK` class and shape your data in a `List<Book>` and bind the grid to the list.

Comment: You do not have to split it, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform

Comment: This list is not static. Based on the requirement I will have one or more lists. So I can't create object for the list. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `BooK` class and shape your data in a `List<Book>` and bind the grid to the list.

**Book**

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Bind data to DataGridView**

```
var list = new List<Book>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Book()
    {
        Title = list1[i],
        Price = list2[i]
    });
}

this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

---

### EDIT

Based on comments, I suppose you have a `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` and you want to add them dynamically to the grid.

I suppose you will use the key of dictionary as header text for the column.

```
//Add your lists to the dictionary
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dictionary.Add("list1", list1);
dictionary.Add("list2", list2);
// And some othet lists ....

//Calculate the count of rows.
int rowCount = dictionary.Cast<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>()
                         .Select(x=>x.Value.Count).Max();

//Create the data table and for each table, add a column
var dataTable = new DataTable();
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add(key);
}

//Add items of each list to the columns of rows of table
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    var row = dataTable.Rows.Add();
    foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
    {
        try
        {
            row[key] = dictionary[key][i];
        }
        catch 
        {
            row[key] = null;
        }
    }
}

//Show data in grid
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: You have mentioned, class Book variables are static. In my scenario I won't get static list. I have modified my question. Hope its clear :) Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RajDeInno No, you don't need static class and I didn't say that, Do you mean you may have dynamic multiple lists?

Comment: Yep. title and book are not static. Its just an example. Similarly I may have 5 or 10 lists.

Comment: You can simply add other fields like `Description`, `Author`, ... to the `Book` model. And fill the list the same way that I did for 2 properties.

Comment: Nah. I don't know whether I am explained clearly. Let me try to clear this further. Actually this list is won't be fixed. Every time it will change. Its a dynamic list. Its based on the customer selection. So I can't go with the above solution.

Comment: OK, So you mean you have some static lists, for example 10 lists that you may want to show 3 of them in the grid based on user selection? For example, the user may want to show Id , Name or maybe he wants to show Name and Price and description , ...?

Comment: Please read my edited post. Its not a static list. Its a dynamic list. What I need is, I need to show the list items in columns. ex, if I have 5 list, I want to display each list items in 5 different columns. If I have 10, I gotta show this in 10 diff columns. Lists are not static. Hope I cleared.

Comment: Trying to understand your edited question :) How do you have dynamic count of lists? Do you have them in a `List<List<String>>` or something like this, for example `Dictionary<string, List<String>>`?

Comment: @RajDeInno I Edited the answer, Hope it help you to solve the problem :)

Comment: @RajDeInno It seems the post answers your question and It would be great if you vote/accept the answer :)

Comment: Thank you  for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to make a `DataTable` and `add` data in it.

As you have the `Lists` you can make a `List` as `column` of `DataTable` and the data you are adding in `List` will be `row` of that `column`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Title");
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Title"] = "THE BOOK OF BURGER";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dt.Columns.Add("Price");
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Price"] = "$200";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

grdBooks.DataSource = dt;
grdBooks.DataBind();
```

If you are receiving `List` you can `loop` through `list` to add data in `Rows` of `DataTable`.