# Adding multiple row from one datagridview to datagridview c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have this piece of code through which i am inserting one grid view data to another

```cs
private void btnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("LOB");
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Packing");
    dt.Columns.Add("Price");
    dt.Columns.Add("Code");
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["LOB"] = txtLOB.Text;
    dr["Quantity"] = txtQuantity.Text;
    dr["Name"] = txtName.Text;
    dr["Packing"] = txtPacking.Text;
    dr["Price"] = txtPrice.Text;
    dr["Code"] = txtBachNo.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    gridviewDtaInserted.DataSource = dt; 
}
```

i am able to insert one row at a time but i want to insert many rows one after another.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should declare DataTable as globally because every time on Button click it has instantiated with new key word.

Comment: That would work however you can allow the user to manually insert rows into the datagridview which would not be reflected into the globale datatable. It is better to get the data from the datagridview itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("LOB");
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Packing");
dt.Columns.Add("Price");
dt.Columns.Add("Code");

private void btnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr;

    for(int i = 0; i <= RowsCountThatYouWantToIsert; i++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["LOB"] = txtLOB.Text;
        dr["Quantity"] = txtQuantity.Text;
        dr["Name"] = txtName.Text;
        dr["Packing"] = txtPacking.Text;
        dr["Price"] = txtPrice.Text;
        dr["Code"] = txtBachNo.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    gridviewDtaInserted.DataSource = dt; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are reading from one view to another you can use a looping structure to go through each iteration. I would suggest a for loop so that you can use the current numerical iteration as part of the instruction. if you want to ammend the first view to the second then you may want to use

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt=(DataTable)DataGridViewer1.datasource;
dt2=(DataTable)DataGridViewer2.datasource;
dt2.Merge(dt);
DataGridViewer2.datasource=dt2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSource` property, from a `DataGridView` accepts a collection of objects. 
So, I would suggest you to add how many rows you want to that public collection of objects, and at the end to update the `DataSource` 
`gridviewDtaInserted.DataSource = myCollection;`

See here more info: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)
Also, here is a [nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform) may help you.

As a skeleton you can design in this way:

```
public class TestFunctional {
    public TestFunctional(){
        DataItems = new List<DataItem>();
    }

    public List<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; }

    private void AddOneItem(){
        var newItem = new DataItem {
            LOB = "a",
            Quantity = 1,
            Name = "A",
            Packing = true,
            Code = "a1"
        };

        DataItems.Add(newItem);

        RefreshGrid();
    }

    private void AddMultipleItems(){
        var newItem1 = new DataItem {
            LOB = "a",
            Quantity = 1,
            Name = "A",
            Packing = true,
            Code = "a1"
        };

        var newItem2 = new DataItem {
            LOB = "b",
            Quantity = 2,
            Name = "B",
            Packing = false,
            Code = "b2"
        };

        DataItems.Add(newItem1);
        DataItems.Add(newItem2);

        /*or use DataItems.AddRange( ... ) */

        RefreshGrid();
    }

    private void RefreshGrid()
    {
        gridviewDtaInserted.Rows.Clear();
        gridviewDtaInserted.Refresh();

        gridviewDtaInserted.DataSource = DataItems;
    }
}

public class DataItem{
    public string LOB { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Packing { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }    
}
```

I hope it will help you. Otherwise, ask :)

---

### **Edit:**

Also, try to use the BindingList instead of List, I am not sure, but maybe it will automatically update the `DataSource` of the grid as soon an item is inserted in the collection.

`BindingList<DataItem> DataItems`