# C# : DGV Verify Cell Content

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've created a software with a datagridview. It can save all data from datagridview.But the problem is data, if a user don't insert data in one cell, software will crash. How i can verify this ? I save dgv content with this code :

```
//Write in file
     StreamWriter ecriture = new StreamWriter(tes, true);



        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {


            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ecriture.Write("\t"+dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()+"\t"+"|");
            }
            ecriture.WriteLine("");

        }
        ecriture.Close();
```

I hope you can help me :)
Thanks from France

Answer (score 0):

You should create a data model, just a class that contains properties which are corresponding to your data grid columns.

```
public class MyModel {
     public string prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

Then bind `BindingList<MyModel>` to your grid like that:

```
dgv.DataSource = myList;
```

And then use that list of objects to obtain data fro grid as oppose to reading text or value from cells.

You can always check if cells has VALUES etc, but that not very Object Oriented approach and also very hard to maintain as code change when you want to reorder columns.

Something to read:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz(v=vs.110).aspx

[Binding List<T> to DataGridView in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform)

If you still want to go your way, make sure that all elements of that chain are not nulls.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()
```

If Row with that index doesn't exist, there is `IndexOutOfRangeException`, same for column with given index. If cell exists but is empty, its `Value` is NULL and then you get `NullReferenceException` because you can't do `ToString` on null object.

Comment: yes but I only want to verify data, one per one. How I can do it ?

Comment: You can still verify item by item on your BindingList. Verifying one by one is not a reason to not do proper programming approaches