# How can i refresh my data in datagridview after in enter new data

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

how can i refresh my datagridview here my code to view my data in datagridview but every time i enter new data i have to reopen my program to see the new data

```
 using (IDbConnection dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection(conn))
        {
            dbconnection.Open();

            SQLiteDataAdapter dataadapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_Sample",conn);
            DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

            dataadapter.Fill(ds,"Info");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
```

Comment: Changing the data source should update the DataGridView - how and where are you running the function?

Comment: in the load function of the form

Comment: Ok - how do you want to refresh the data? Does the user click a button? Or refreshed at certain time intervals?

Comment: every time the user enters new data in the database i want to refresh the datagridview so i can view the new data

Comment: How is the user entering data into the database?

Comment: the user can enter info in the database by the UI i made and can view the that gridview on it but every time i enter new data have to rerun the program so the new data will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `DataSet` or a `DataTable` as a datasource for the `DataGridView`, you can try something like this:

```
private void LoadDataToDgv()
{
    using (IDbConnection dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection(conn))
    {
        dbconnection.Open();

        SQLiteDataAdapter dataadapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_Sample",conn);
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

        dataadapter.Fill(ds,"Info");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }
}
```

And then after you have added the new data to your tables, fetch the new dataset and reload the grid with the new rows:

```
//Code to add new data to Sql Table
  LoadDataToDgv();
```

I would however recommend that you create a Class for the type of item you are binding to the grid (if you haven't created one yet) and the use BindingList to do the same. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform) question describes well how to use it for binding it as a source for DataGridViews.

Comment: it work but there a way that i can automatically refresh the datagridview in the load function?

Comment: If by automatically you mean that just that new inserted record is added to the grid, then no, I don't think that can be done. You will have to rebind the data source in order to show the new records.

Answer (score 0):

i put the refresh function every time i put new data in the database so the datagridview will refresh every new data i enter

```
   public void AddData()
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection(conn))
        {
            dbconnection.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbconnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_sample (Name,Age) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')"; ;
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                        SQLiteDataAdapter dataadapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_Sample", conn);
                        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

                        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Info");
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                    dbconnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```