# Show only specific columns in datagridview from multiple tables

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image: here is model pic]

I would like to show list in datagridview, but having specific columns: **GodinaUpisa, BrojIndeksa, Ime i Prezime, Ocena**.

I get Ime i Prezime by overriding toString() in class Student.

This is short version of code. there is also while loop etc., `citac=Reader`, `lista= new List<Polozio>()` is returned after method is executed, everything working well except for the following part because I dont know how to do It.

SQL:

`SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TPolozio 
    INNER JOIN TStudent ON (TStudent.[BrojIndeksa] = TPolozio.[BrojIndeksa]) AND (TStudent.[GodinaUpisa] = TPolozio.[GodinaUpisa]) 
WHERE 
    SifraPredmeta="+p.SifraPredmeta+" 
ORDER BY
    TPolozio.GodinaUpisa`

here is part of the code:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.GodinaUpisa = citac.GetInt32(0);
s.BrInd = citac.GetInt32(1);
s.Ime = citac.GetString(2);
s.Prezime = citac.GetString(3);
s.Godina = citac.GetInt32(4);

Polozio po = new Polozio();
po.BrPrijave = citac.GetInt32(5);
po.Student = s;
po.Predmet = p;
po.Ocena = citac.GetInt32(9);
lista.Add(po);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding List<T> to DataGridView in WinForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform)

Comment: @JericCruz what is at least similar to that question ? :)

Comment: Please read carefully the duplicate question.... you can just assigned your list of `Polozio` class to datagrid. just like this.. `var bindingList = new BindingList<Polozio>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
grid.DataSource = source;`

Comment: but that is not my question. I wrote that everything is working well, and I didnt include that part of the code at all. The problem is to show exactly specific columns from multiple tables, so sql query could be different, and part of the method I posted. This is totally different question, but dont get me wrong thanks for effort, I appreciate It.

Comment: Yep, your question is different. I posted an answer below see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add columns to your DataGridView in your code like this

> This will determine the column in your DataGridView:

`dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ID", "ID");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");`

And you can use LINQ `ForEach` to the list and add it to your `DataGridView`.

```
list.ForEach(m =>
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(m.ID, m.Name); //in your case, this is properties of Polozio class.
                }
            );
```

if you're not familiar with `ForEach` you can just use `For` loop in your list.

[image]