# How can I edit null values in a BindingList when a DataGridView is bound to it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I am still very new to data binding in Windows Forms with Visual Basic .NET, but trying to get familiar with it. I tried looking for information on this already, but to no avail.

I want to set up two-way binding between a `DataGridView` control and a list of objects (let's say they are of a made-up type called `MyListElementClass`), in a manner similar to what I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695971) to another question. Below is my implementation for `MyListElementClass`, in a file called **MyListElementClass.vb**:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

<Serializable>
Public NotInheritable Class MyListElementClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Implements IMyListElementClass

#Region "Fields"
    Private _a As UShort
    Private _b As Double
    Private _c, _d, _e As Boolean

    ' End fields region.
#End Region

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged implementation"
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    ' End INotifyPropertyChanged implementation region.
#End Region

#Region "IMyListElementClass implementation"
    Public Property PropertyA As UShort Implements IMyListElementClass.PropertyA
        Get
            Return _a
        End Get
        Set(value As UShort)
            If _a <> value Then
                _a = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PropertyB As Double Implements IMyListElementClass.PropertyB
        Get
            Return _b
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            If _b <> value Then
                _b = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PropertyC As Boolean Implements IMyListElementClass.PropertyC
        Get
            Return _c
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If _c <> value Then
                _c = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PropertyD As Boolean Implements IMyListElementClass.PropertyD
        Get
            Return _d
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If _d <> value Then
                _d = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PropertyE As Boolean Implements IMyListElementClass.PropertyE
        Get
            Return _e
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If _e <> value Then
                _e = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    ' End IMyListElementClass implementation region.
#End Region

#Region "Constructors"
    Public Sub New()
        PropertyA = 0
        PropertyB = 0
        PropertyC = False
        PropertyD = False
        PropertyE = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(a As UShort, b As Double, c As Boolean, d As Boolean, e As Boolean)
        Me.PropertyA = a
        Me.PropertyB = b
        Me.PropertyC = c
        Me.PropertyD = d
        Me.PropertyE = e
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(other As IMyListElementClass)
        If other Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(other))
        CopyFrom(other)
    End Sub

    ' End constructors region.
#End Region

#Region "Methods"
    Public Sub CopyFrom(other As IMyListElementClass)
        If other Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(other))
        With other
            PropertyA = .PropertyA
            PropertyB = .PropertyB
            PropertyC = .PropertyC
            PropertyD = .PropertyD
            PropertyE = .PropertyE
        End With
    End Sub

    ' End methods region.
#End Region
End Class
```

The idea here is that the `DataGridView` control will show a list of available "slots" (rows) that instances of `MyListElementClass` can be entered into. *However, some of these slots could be empty, and may need to be filled in or cleared later.* The number of rows in the table is specified by a number entered elsewhere, so the user cannot add or remove rows on the fly; They have to work with the space that's given.

My current attempt at this is to have the `DataGridView` control bound to a `BindingList(Of MyListElementClass)`, where *its size is always equal to the number of available slots and empty slots are represented by null elements*. However, I found that if I have these null values present in the `BindingList(Of MyListElementClass)`, these rows cannot be edited by the user in the `DataGridView` control which is bound to it, and I'm not really sure how to handle this.

An example of what I'm trying to do in my user control which contains the `DataGridView` (named `dgvDataGridView` here and with columns already set up through the designer):

```
Public Class MyUserControl

    Private _myBindingList As BindingList(Of MyListElementClass)

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        dgvDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False ' Columns already created through the Visual Studio designer with the ordering and header text I want.
        SetUpTableDataBinding()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetUpTableDataBinding()
        colA.DataPropertyName = NameOf(MyListElementClass.PropertyA)
        colB.DataPropertyName = NameOf(MyListElementClass.PropertyB)
        colC.DataPropertyName = NameOf(MyListElementClass.PropertyC)
        colD.DataPropertyName = NameOf(MyListElementClass.PropertyD)
        colE.DataPropertyName = NameOf(MyListElementClass.PropertyE)

        Dim initialList As New List(Of MyListElementClass)(Enumerable.Repeat(Of MyListElementClass)(Nothing, 1)) ' First row will contain a null value, and hence be "empty".
        _myBindingList = New BindingList(Of MyListElementClass)(initialList)
        Dim source = New BindingSource(_myBindingList, Nothing)
        dgvDataGridView.DataSource = source

        ' Some test data for data binding.
        _myBindingList.AddNew() ' Adds a new MyListElementClass instance with default property values.
        _myBindingList.Add(New MyListElementClass(2345, 7.4, False, True, False)) ' Just some sample values.
    End Sub

End Class
```

After this user control loads, I can see an empty row, a row with default values for the `MyListElementClass`, and a row with some sample values appear, for three rows total. I can edit the second and third rows, but not the first (any values I enter immediately vanish).

Again, in completely unfamiliar territory here, so bear with me. If I cannot get this to work, then I will abandon this idea and return to manually setting and retrieving data in the `DataGridView` cells like I've always done up until now.

Comment: Cannot repro, but most of that `SetUpTableDataBinding` code isnt needed.  a) you dont need to create a List in order to fill a BindingList b) You dont need a BindingSource for a BindingList.  c) The DGV will get column datatypes from the source, even then "PropertyA" is all you need vs reflection to get the name.

Comment: @Plutonix The code I use mentioned in your points a) and b) is following from the answer I linked in my question. I'm aware that you can bind a DataGridView directly to a BindingList, but I was under the impression that it's best practice to always bind to a BindingSource (or is it not?). In response to point c), I set up the DataPropertyName of each column so I can show friendlier column names to the user in a specified order, and so if I change the property names later then it's easier to refactor.

Comment: `DataPropertyName` has nothing to do whit what the user sees.  It is the name of the column to bind to.

Comment: @Plutonix I know. But if I don't explicitly set this and instead let the columns be autogenerated, then the user will see `PropertyA`, `PropertyB`, etc. in the headers instead of what I want to display. I have to let each column know which property it is supposed to correspond to since I created them manually through the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null values cannot be edited, replace them with empty strings instead and I think you will find that it will work as intended.

Comment: This would not compile for me as given; did you mean the [`IsDBNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx) function? But even with that tweak, this code has no effect in comparison to what I have already.

Comment: Sorry, was late when I wrote that and I was tired.  Yes, IsDBNull.  No impact?  Ok ... I'll take a closer look at it now that I'm rested ... lol ...

Comment: Unfortunately I use VS 2013, not 2015.  A lot of code you use (for example "NameOF") isn't available until VS 2015.  The line of code I'm interested in exploring is `Dim initialList As New List(Of MyListElementClass)(Enumerable.Repeat(Of MyListElementClass)(Nothing, 1))` , the reason I'm looking at this is that it generates null values in the datagrid, I believe that's your issue, you can't edit null.

Comment: The addition of null in my case is intentional. I need a way to represent both in my `DataGridView` and the list of `MyListElementClass` I retrieve from it for further processing empty rows, and I figured I could do this simply by inserting null values and letting the user fill those in later with actual instances. Unless there's a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: I would use null strings, "", instead of null.  Practically it's the same result and can be edited.

Comment: So null values cannot be edited and have to be replaced with empty strings instead. A little disappointing... Anyways, I took your suggestion and built upon it by creating a wrapper class around `MyListElementClass` which exposes `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` of its contained object as strings instead of numerical values, and uses string parsing for setting new values. Then I changed the BindingList to contain instances of this wrapper class instead of `MyListElementClass` itself, and now it seems to work as intended. If you change your answer to suggest this instead, then I will accept it.