# Data from BindingSource not loaded in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a List of `MeetingDisplay` `List<Modells.MeetingDisplay> overview`: I want to display it on a complettly clear DataGridView now. Doing it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform), the data is in the `BindingSource`, but does not load into the DataGridView.

```
bindingList = new BindingList<Modells.MeetingDisplay>(overview);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Do I have to configure the DataGridView first before adding the datasource?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on the 3rd line and run the code, when it breaks, hover over bindingList and see what it holds. If there is information there, then I would suspect the dataGridView (did you originally do anything with it and then restructure your code to use a datasource) A simple test would be to drag a new dataGridView onto the form and set its DataSource to `source`. Just to ensure you're working with a stock DGV

Comment: Yes you do. You should add columns to your DataGridView by setting their "DataPropertyName", mapping them to the fields of you MeetingDisplay class