# Display the sum of all items inside listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Is it possible to sum up all of the item's price inside a ListBox? I have this ListBox that displays items from a DataGridView, and each of their prices are in `priceTextBox` Please refer from the picture below.

[image]

What I want to do is to display the sum of all the item's price and display it at the `totalTextBox`.

I have already done this code but I think this won't work.

```
private void menuListBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        string Str;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in menuDataGrid.Rows)  //this part displays the price of each item to a textbox so this is good.
        {         
            if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(menuListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {                   
                pricetxtbox.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();                                     
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (string Str in row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Equals(menuListBox.SelectedItem.ToString())) //now this is the part where I want to happen the adding the prices of all items in the listbox. this also gives me an error at row saying it doesn't exist in the context 
        {
            x = x + Convert.ToInt32(Str);
            totaltxtbox.Text = x;
        } 
    }
```

Will appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: The `row` object only exists within the first `foreach` loop, so move the second `foreach` inside the first one. You don't need (or want) the `break` either.

Comment: I need a little clarification. Are you searching the DataGridView for the selected item in the ListBox and then displaying that price? If so, are there more than one matching items in the DataGridView for an item in the ListBox? Is the total supposed to be a total of all of the prices regardless of the selected item in the ListBox?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad The items from the ListBox are from a DataGridView. Ill drag an item to the ListBox and it will add the items' `MenuCode`. If I select an item inside the ListBox the `MenuPrice will isplay on the first TextBox. Now what I want to happen is that if I have 2 items in the ListBox, for example the price is 100 and 50, the sum of two will add up and appear to the second TextBox. I will edit my post and include the DataGridView where I get the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out...

```
Func<string, DataGridViewRow> getRow = (menuCode) =>
{
    return menuDataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .First(r => ((string)r.Cells[3].Value).Equals(menuCode));
};

var selected = menuListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
pricetxtbox.Text = getRow(selected).Cells[5].Value.ToString();

totaltxtbox.Text = menuListBox.Items.Cast<object>()
    .Select(o => o.ToString())
    .Select(i => (int)getRow(i).Cells[5].Value)
    .Sum()
    .ToString();
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. And it did the trick..Thank you! Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your approach, by separating completely data and display.
To do that, you could create a class which will contain data for each row of your DataGrid :

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your codebehind, you store a list of these items :

```
private List<MyItem> AllItems = new List<MyItem>();
```

Finally, you set this collection as the source of your DataGrid :

```
menuDataGrid.DataSource = AllItems;
```

Then, all your data is stored in a collection you own, and to sum prices it's much simpler :

```
using System.Linq;

private int ComputeSum()
{
    return (AllItems.Sum(item => item.Price));
}
```

The next step is to use Binding and a [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx), wich allows the DataGrid to refresh automatically when new items are added in "AllItems": see [this well explained post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform/16695971#16695971).

Comment: Hello @Elo. I will consider this and will try. Thank you!