# how to display Dictionary values to Data Grid View in window forms

Tags: c#, gridview

```
public static Dictionary<int, Account> accSavingList = new Dictionary<int,Account>();
```

[Dictionary[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQUpN.png)I have created a `Dictionary<int, Account>` acc which stores a value as a following :
`int(Account number)`: takes a value from windows form
`Account`(account class data type): takes  3 values (account name, balance,minimum balance ).

Now i want to display dictionary values to data grid view which has 4 columns:
'account no' 'account name' 'balance' 'minimum balance'.

i have used:

```
gridView.DataSource=Account.accSavingList;
```

But that is not working

Comment: `But that is not working` please translate this to english.. And share your code too....

Comment: when gridView.DataSource=Account.accList is not working

Comment: neither it is showing me any error

Comment: Dictionaries can not be DataBound to GridView, you need to bind GridView to the List of accounts.

Comment: Sir , can u tell me how to bind grid view to list

Comment: Create list of accounts and set it to gridView.DataSource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform

Comment: I already created a list of accounts :-savinggridView.DataSource=Account.accSavingList;.

Comment: What you need to do is `var accounts = Account.accSavingList.Values.ToList(); gridView.DataSource = acocunts;`.

Comment: still getting the empty grid on running the applications..

Comment: I usually just put results into a DataTable which shows up better in a DGV,

Comment: You may have more than one issue. Troubleshoot by creating a hard-coded list and get binding working. Then move on to binding your dynamic data.

Comment: I didn't get u .....could u please elaborate -@Crowcoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the grid will display the values correctly depends on how you have configured your grid and it's column bindings, but here is how you can flatten your dictionary into a proper datasource (I am guessing at property names so you will not be able to directly copy this code) :

```
//a.Value is the Account class instance from each dictionary entry
var acclist = accSavingList.Select( a => new {
    AccountNo = a.Key,
    AccountName = a.Value.AccountName,
    Balance = a.Value.Balance,
    MinimumBalance = a.Value.MinimumBalance
}).ToList();

gridView.DataSource = acclist;
```