# how to truncate a table and update the datagridview that is link with the table

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh, truncate

I really really need help. I am making a student violation system and I need to make a button that can delete all the records I have in my table and in my datagridview that is linked to that table. so when i click the button, it should ask for confirmation then when the user click the YES. the table will be truncated and the records in the datagridview will refresh. I'm having a hard time, can you please help me? Thankyou.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "Truncate table [transaction]";
            using (SqlConnection xcon = new SqlConnection(@"Server=GLR\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SE_Project;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand xcom = new SqlCommand(query, xcon))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter xdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(xcom);
                    try
                    {
                        xcon.Open();
                        if (this.dataGridViewAdminTransac.DataSource != null)
                        {
                            this.dataGridViewAdminTransac.DataSource = null;
                            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.dataGridViewAdminTransac.Rows.Clear();
                            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }

                        AdminView temp = new AdminView();
                        temp.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        xcon.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont ;-)  Let the framework do the work for you.  Use a BindingList.  You update the BindingList.  The framework updates the DataGridView.

See Jürgen Steinblock's answer here for the mechanism: [Binding List<T> to DataGridView in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform)