# c# highlight cells in a data grid view where one specific cell is duplicate and any other cell is duplicate

Tags: c#, datagridview, duplicates, highlight

Hello I have a datagridview that is populated with data let's say name, age and hobby.

Now I want fields to be hilighted where the age is duplicate and either the name or the hobby and both are duplicate but the age needs to be duplicate for the field to
be hilighted.

So far I have found code for highlighting the row where the age is identical and highlighting the age column in this row:

```
var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()

var duplettes = rows.GroupBy(dgvrow => dgvrow.Cells["age"].Value.ToString())
            .Where(item => item.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(dgvrow => dgvrow.ToList());


    foreach (var row in duplettes)
{
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            row.Cells["age"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

If two kids have the same age I want their age to be highlighted by changing the fore color and i want the row in which they appear in to be highlighted by changing the backcolor.

If two kids are called bob (or sally or whatever, the name just needs to be identical) and their age is identical I want their names to be highlited by changing the forecolor.

Now if two kids are named bob (or sally or whatever, the name just needs to be identical) and they both have an age of which a duplicate exits but they do not have the same age i do not want their name to be highlighted.

Same thing for hobbies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I am assuming you want rows highlighted that satisfy the logical condition `row1.age == row2.age => (row1.name == row2.name || row1.hobby == row2.hobby)`. Please let me know if you seek a different condition.

Edit: Apologies, my initial answer set the yellow color incorrectly

Edit 2: Updated version that should actually change the grid view

Edit 3: Use different method for updating rows

Edit 4: Clears datasource, then adds modified list including old values

```
public void HighlightRows()
{
    var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToList();

    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

    MatchAllRows(rows);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(rows.ToArray());
}

private void MatchAllRows(List<DataGridViewRow> rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count() - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < rows.Count(); j++)
            if (rows[i].Cells["age"] == rows[j].Cells["age"])
                MatchTwoRows(rows[i], rows[j]);
}

private void MatchTwoRows(DataGridViewRow row1, DataGridViewRow row2)
{
    void Match(string key)
    {
        if (row1.Cells[key].Value == row2.Cells[key].Value)
        {
            row1.Cells[key].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            row2.Cells[key].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            row1.Cells[key].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            row2.Cells[key].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }

    List<string> keys = new List<string> { "name", "age", "hobby" };

    foreach (string key in keys)
        Match(key);
}
```

Comment: Somehow this wouldn't work for me, nothing was highlighted. To more thoroughly explain what needs to be highlighted i made this picture here: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/180703/b2whhuzc.png

Comment: in the pic i accidentally called the datagridviewrows dataviewrows

Comment: @moriturus: thanks for the picture. I think my application logic is doing what you want, I just was modifying a copy from ToList(). I have updated my solution with what is hopefully a fix

Comment: the bindinglist as a datasource does not quite work (the datagridview shows the settings of the list e.g. readonly instead of the values. do you have any idea how i could change it?

Comment: @moriturus: I was just looking at the code and spotted that bug. Sorry, I wish I could test it myself. I think I will be able to fix it

Comment: @moriturus: I updated it again. I realized that if you want to update using the datasource, you need some sort of [list of classes as the source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695971/2303560)

Comment: I am completely clearing out the table, then reloading it. There's probably a better way though

Comment: clearing out the table doesn't work, first of all c# refuses to do it (System.argument Exception) and also this way the lines that have no duplicates would disappear from the result

Comment: To simplify the application logic, you could bind the datasource to a bindinglist, then manipulate that directly