# Populating a DataGrid with a List from a custom Class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a class with a property that holds a list of a custom object.

```
// MySongs.cs
public class MySongs
{    
    public List<Song> Songs = new List<Song>();
}
```

The Songs property gets populated in *MainWindow()*.

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs
MySongs.Songs.Add(new Song("Hey Jude", "The Beatles"));
```

How can I display the *MySongs.Songs* list in a DataGrid with Title and Artist as headers?

Thanks!

**Edit (10/27):**

Here is the XAML in *MainWindow.xaml*:

```
<Window x:Class="MySongsUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySongsUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="My Songs" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>

        <!-- DataGrid with Songs -->
        <DataGrid x:Name="songsDataGrid" />

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Here is the C# in *MySongs.cs*:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MySongsUI
{
    public static class MySongs
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<Song> Songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>();
    }
}
```

Here is the C# in *Song.cs*:

```
namespace MySongsUI
{
    public class Song
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        public Song(string title, string artist)
        {
            Title = title;
            Artist = artist;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I'm not sure of the best way to make the *MySongs* class be recognized in the XAML of *MainWindow.xaml* so I can bind it to the DataGrid.

Thank you!

Comment: I Think this link is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example code that will auto generate all your columns according to the properties of the Song class:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySongs}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid >
```

If you want anything custom, you will need to style it.

Don't forget to set the list to be an ObservableCollection and the Song class to inherit from NotificationObject if you want to make changes to them on runtime.

Hope this helps..

**Edit:**

Here is how it should look like:

**MainWindlow:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <local:MainView />
</Window>
```

**MainView.xaml.cs:**

```
public MainView()
        {
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

**MainView.xaml:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding local:MySongs.Songs}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    </DataGrid >
```

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MySongs MySongs { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MySongs = new MySongs()
            {
                Songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>()
                {
                    new Song("Hey Jude", "The Beatles")
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

You will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on MainViewModel, Song and MySongs in order to support runtime change of the data.

Comment: Do I need to set a DataContext somewhere or something? I'm not getting any data into the DataGrid and there is data in MySongs.

Comment: If I set the ItemSource in code it works as expected, but I was hoping to be able to set the ItemSource in XAML.

songsDataGrid.ItemsSource = MySongs.Songs;

Comment: Can you add your xaml?

Comment: @T Gregory I have edited my answer and added some sample code that will explain my answer.

Comment: @Elibi - I updated my original comment with more code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're doing it wrong my friend, read about MVVM Methodology to better understand the development of wpf applications correctly. In the meanwhile, look at my answer, it's proper MVVM and will help you to get a glimps of it.

Comment: MySongs.cs is my ViewModel, MainWindow.xaml is my View, and the Data is coming from a function in MainWindow.cs that I could break out into its own class.

I got it to work as expected though!

Comment: @T Gregory, glad it worked out. If I answered your question correctly, please accept it so that others may learn and use it.