# Cannot update datagridview after add data to View

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, instance

My Datagridview is not refreshed. After I restart the application it refresh.

When I was using Instance(static method) it was getting the changes to the datagridview.

```
ucEmirGor.Instance.Listele();

public  void Listele()
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = managerV_WRKORD.List();
}
```

Expect that no need to restart for refresh datagridview.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Do you try to change the content of the datasource and the datagrid is not refreshed? when should the datagrid refresh?

Comment: @SebastianSiemens I  just tried to call Listele() after I press the button but is it wrong ?

Comment: Are you calling `dataGridView1.DataBind()` after setting the DataSource?

Comment: @JesusPocoata there is no option as DataBind() for datagridview there is a just DataBindings();

Comment: My mistake, `DataBind()` method is only available in webforms but not in winforms. Maybe setting the DataSource to null before updating with `managerV_WRKORD.List();` could fix it.

Comment: Is the Button on the same Form?

Comment: @SebastianSiemens Yes the button is on the same form

Comment: if the button is on the same form you can just call Listele() without form.instance...

Comment: best practice for datagridview is to use bindinglist or bindingsource. Look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `List<T>` as the datasource.

Use `BindingList<T>` instead.