# Selecting row in datagridview clears list within a selected object

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

This may be a shot in the dark, but I seem to have this strange bug in my code. I have a system that stores a bunch of vehicle objects (class is called Vehicle) in a `VehicleList` stored in a Business class. Each of these vehicles has a list attribute called activities, which stores different types of `Activities`. Currently I have a system that adds the vehicles to a datagridview where I can select a record and it opens up a form with a list of the vehicles activities where I can add and remove them etc. This works fine with adding the activities to the list in the current selected vehicle. The problem I am having, which could be an underlying issue, is that when I open the vehicle list form and select a vehicle to view its activity list, it removes all records from the list. I have done some debugging and found that the activities are stored in the list of that vehicle right up until I click a row in the datagridview.

The hierarchy looks like this:

```
<Business> //Contains VehicleList
   <VehicleList> //Contains Vehicles
      <Vehicle> //Contains ActivityList 
         <ActivityList> //Contains Activities
```

Here is the method I use to select a row:

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            string registration = dataGridViewRegisteredVehicles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            foreach (Vehicle vehicle in Business.VehicleList)
            {
                if (vehicle.Registration == registration)
                {
                    _selectedVehicle = vehicle;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is not a record", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Where `_selectedVehicle` =

```
    private Vehicle _selectedVehicle;

    public Vehicle SelectedVehicle
    {
        get { return _selectedVehicle; }

        set
        {
            _selectedVehicle = value;
        }
    }
```

Here is the list in the Vehicle class:

```
    private List<Activity> _activityList = new List<Activity>();

    public List<Activity> ActivityList
    {
        get => _activityList;
    }
```

I cant wrap my head around why the list is cleared when I click a record. I checked the list before I clicked a record in the datagridview and it showed a correct count for the amount of activities in the list, but when I check the list afterwards, the list count is zero. Has anyone seen this before?

Method for adding vehicles to the vehicle list:

```
                            Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle
                            {
                                Registration = registration,
                                Model = model,
                                Make = make,
                                Year = int.Parse(year),
                                Cost = int.Parse(cost)
                            };

                            Business.VehicleList.Add(vehicle);
```

Method for adding from list to datagridview:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Business.VehicleList.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridViewRegisteredVehicles.Rows.Add(
                Business.VehicleList[i].Registration,
                Business.VehicleList[i].Model,
                Business.VehicleList[i].Make,
                Business.VehicleList[i].Year,
                Business.VehicleList[i].Cost
                );
        }
```

I tried setting the datagridview datasource to the list, but this just adds empty cells to the datagridview

Comment: The issue you are facing is `_selectedVehicle .ActivityList` becomes empty when you select a Vehicle from the GridView. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: While debugging did you see if `vehicle.ActivityList` is empty or not?

Comment: it shows that the list contains activities before I click a row, but empty after I click the row. I added a couple of test buttons to get the list count before and after. I also manually declared a vehicle for test purposes so that I didn't have to click the datagridview, and the form with the activity list showed all of the activities

Comment: _” Currently I have a system that adds the vehicles to a datagridview… “_ … How does your “system” add the vehicles to the `DataGridView`? If it sets the grids `DataSource`, then it is unnecessary to “loop” through the data source. Simply “cast” the “selected” row to a `Vehicle` object.

Comment: Ive added some code to the bottom of my question

Comment: _” I tried setting the datagridview datasource to the list, but this just adds empty cells to the datagridview”_ … then either the list is empty or the code is not being implemented correctly. … `dataGridViewRegisteredVehicles.DataSource = Business.VehicleList` … should display all the “publicly” exposed properties in `Vehicle` that are not other classes or collections. The properties in the posted `Vehicle` class may not display since they are not “public” properties. Just a guess as I do not see this class definition.

Comment: Ive changed it from a for loop to `_selectedVehicle = Business.VehicleList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Registration == registration);`

Comment: Again, looping through the list (LINQ or NOT) is unnecessary if `Business.VehicleList` is used as a `DataSource` to the grid. In the cell click event, you could then do something like… `Vehicle _selectedVehicle = (Vehicle)datagridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;`

Comment: I set the datasource of the datagridview to null, then set it to the Business.VehicleList and it has added two empty rows to the datagridview. There are currently two vehicles in the list

Comment: I am not trying to dissuade you from what you are doing, however, I would like to point out that setting the grids data source may appear unnecessary, and in some cases it may well be, however, almost ALL the code you are going to write in reference to this problem and your previous question can be avoided IF you use the list as a data source to those objects.

Comment: Example… Your last code snippet loops through the list and adds the items from the list to the rows in the grid. This does two things 1) “Disconnects” the grid from the data source (list) 2) and because of 1 you end up having to write the code that adds the rows to grid, also you need to write the code that finds out “which” item is “selected” when the user clicks a row. All this can be avoided IF you set the grids `DataSource`. Just a thought.

Comment: I tried this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695971/15914989, but it still produces the issue of inserting all empty rows

Comment: _”… but it still produces the issue of inserting all empty rows”_ … I refer to my previous comment… if the row(s) are empty… THEN, … the list is empty or contains rows of empty values… OR … the code is not properly implementing this (I see no code for this) … OR … there is something going on after the data source has been set. I can assure you this WILL work and I suggest your efforts be put towards figuring this out as opposed to writing a bunch of unnecessary code. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to get it working. Really appreciate it. I used your method and it works