# Binding DatagridView to List Provides "Extra" columns at runtime

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a list of  objects called "TournamentPlayers" (derived from a class "PlayerInfo") in my project.

I have applied the following code to bind the `lstTournPlayers` to a DataGridView:

```
    ' Bind List of TournamentPlayers to Datagridview
    Dim bindingList = New BindingList(Of TournamentPlayers)(lstTournPlayers)
    Dim source = New BindingSource(bindingList, Nothing)
    dgvPlayers.DataSource = source

    dgvMembershipNo.DataPropertyName = "strMembershipNo"
    dgvPlayerName.DataPropertyName = "strMembershipName"
```

Found from an answer here on SO, but repurposed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16695971/692250

However, I noticed that after setting up the columns within the datagrid view, I get this weird column heading now:

[image: DataGridView header at runtime]

My question is: how can I bind the parts of the list to this datagridview.

*For anyone interested here is the schema of the list:*

```
Public Class PlayerInfo
    Public strPlayerFirstName As String
    Public strPlayerLastName As String
    Public strMembershipNo As String
    Public strMembershipName As String
End Class
Public Class TournamentPlayers : Inherits PlayerInfo
    Public intStatus As Integer = 0
    Public intByeRounds As Integer
    Public intTeamID As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Where is `lstTournPlayers` defined? And… what are `dgvMembershipNo` and `dgvPlayerName` …? … I assume they are columns in the grid, but this is unknown. Are you manually adding the columns manually in the designer? I do not see how those columns would be created “automatically” using the class you show.

Comment: Yeah I badly named the columns of the original dgv. but yes, `dgvMembershipNo` and `dgvPlayerName` are two of the columns defined in the designer view. lstTournament Players is defined in the same Form.

Comment: I am betting you need to make the class items “Properties” by adding the `Property` qualifier like… `Public Property strPlayerFirstName As String` …

Comment: Okay that added MORE columns but I still can't seem to bind them to the ones in the designer.

Comment: Well... it is not clear how `dgvMembershipNo` is defined. In other words... I would think this would be done in the designer.

Comment: No worries, was hoping to use a list but it seems more difficult to do it that way. I guess I'll just loop and add that way.

Comment: I haven’t a clue what you mean by… _”I guess I'll just loop and add that way.”_ … ?... And using a `BindingSource` is a better approach than using a simple `List<T>`  I am not sure why it will not work… in my small test… “In the designer” I select the column and set its `DataPropertyName`… You can also do this outside the designer, but since you are defining the columns IN the designer anyway… it makes no sense to set its `DataPropertyName` somewhere else.

Comment: Which .NET Framework are you using? I'm not able to add any data sources to my project since it's using .NET 6 and have to strictly use code.

Comment: I tested this using .Net 4.8. But if you say you have to do this... then go for it. Good Luck.

Comment: Create your columns in the designer and set their `DataPropertyName` in the designer. Also, make those members of your classes properties rather than fields and get rid of the Hungarian prefixes.

Comment: Is there no way to keep the Hungarian prefix but give the column a regular name?